# C# extension method overloading causes "missing assembly reference" error

Tags: c#, extension-methods, c#-5.0

*There is a corresponding VS dev ticket https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817276/error-cs0012-the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-issued-for-an-extension-method-that-is-not-used*

I have 2 extension methods:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Class `HttpRequestMessage` is located in `System.Net.Http` assembly and `HttpRequestBase` is in `System.Web` (i.e. in different assemblies). The class `ExtensionMethods` is located in lets say **ProjectA**.

This project compiles well and has no issues.

Then I use the first method `GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestBase request)` from another project (lets say **ProjectB**), like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    var sessionContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISessionContext>();

    // Call to GetClientIpAddress
    sessionContext.ClientIpAddress =
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetClientIpAddress();
}
```

The ProjectB already has a reference to `System.Web`, but when I try to compile it, it causes an compiler error:

> The type '`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly '`System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`'.

What I dont understand is why should I add a reference to `System.Net.Http`.

It seems that the compiler tries to use the second method `GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)` and this causes a missing reference to the assembly. Is this a bug?

When I rename the first method (i.e. get rid of overloads) everything compiles well.

Comment: It is possible that extension method is using some assembly that is not referenced in Web project

Comment: Until the compiler can see the definitions for all types, **it** doesn't *know* that you intend to call the first method. It needs to see all of the types to perform overload resolution

Comment: The ProjectB already has both references to System.Net.Http and System.Web, so this is not a case. See my edit below.

Comment: You forgot to document your .NET framework target.  But high odds that you picked 4.0 and inappropriately used the Client profile for your EXE project.  Change it to the full version, the one that also includes System.Web

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant

Comment: @Alex, you are wrong. C# 5.0 [exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions). It features asynchronous methods and caller info attributes.

Comment: Uh, interesting. Didn't know versioning differs between framework and language. Amending the comment.

Comment: "It seems that the compiler tries to use the second method..." - no, as I tried to indicate in my first comment, it's not even getting that far. It's found a symbol in your code, `GetClientIpAddress`. It's now got to work out which method you intended to call. It's found two candidates. It now needs to work out which of the two candidates it should call. In order to do that, it needs to understand all argument types of *both* methods, in order to work out the single best method, or if the call is ambiguous, etc. It can't do that if it doesn't understand the argument types of the second method.

Comment: Both extension methods are in scope, so the compiler must evaluate both of them. If you are using these extensions from different projects and the missing reference is irrelevant for some of them, split the static class and put the parts in different namespaces. There is an explanation here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817276/error-cs0012-the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-issued-for-an-extension-method-that-is-not-used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From C# 5.0 spec, section 7.5.3:

> Given the set of applicable candidate function members, the best function member in that set is located. If the set contains only one function member, then that function member is the best function member. Otherwise, the best function member is the one function member that is better than all other function members with respect to the given argument list, provided that each function member is compared to all other function members using the rules in §7.5.3.2.

Section 7.5.3.2:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions { E<sub>1</sub>, E<sub>2</sub>, ..., E<sub>N</sub> } and two applicable function members M<sub>P</sub> and M<sub>Q</sub> with parameter types { P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, ..., P<sub>N</sub> } and { Q<sub>1</sub>, Q<sub>2</sub>, ..., Q<sub>N</sub> }, M<sub>P</sub> is defined to be a ***better function member*** than M<sub>Q</sub> if
>
> • for each argument, the implicit conversion from E<sub>X</sub> to Q<sub>X</sub> is not better than the implicit conversion from E<sub>X</sub> to P<sub>X</sub>, and
>
> • for at least one argument, the conversion from E<sub>X</sub> to P<sub>X</sub> is better than the conversion from E<sub>X</sub> to Q<sub>X</sub>.

There's no rule "if the argument type exactly matches the parameter type, pick that one" - so the compiler needs complete type information about all parameter types in order to be able to assess the above rules.

In order to resolve the issue without having to add a reference to `System.Net.Http`? You've already found the answer - use different method names. That let's you succeed because of the previously quoted part of 7.5.3:

> If the set contains only one function member, then that function member is the best function member

Comment: Yes, I agree that "...so the compiler needs complete type information about all parameter types in order to be able to assess the above rules." I think it already has all needed information because ProjectA already has a reference to System.Net.Http and the compiler can use it to resolve the parameter type. Correct?

Comment: @neleus - no, references aren't transitive. When it's compiling project B, it only has the code of project B and its references to consider.

Comment: Now I see, thanks for the detailed description. In this case I would suggest to Microsoft to improve their compiler, it would be really nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

I also made a simple test without extension methods and got the same effect.
As Damien_The_Unbeliever said, the issue is related to method overloading only.